# PHP preg_match pair of numbers or letters

Tags: php, preg-match

I have made a preg_match code a while ago that checks for license plates.

```
return preg_match("/^([0-9A-Za-z])"."([0-9A-Za-z])"."(\-([0-9A-Za-z])"."([0-9A-Za-z]))"."(\-([0-9A-Za-z])"."([0-9A-Za-z]))$/", $kenteken );
```

It checks the plates like this: `u0-99-e5` So number or letter, a `-` and then the same again.
Now that was not the solution according to my teacher. It has to check for PAIRS of numbers or letters. So `99-oo-ii` for example.

How do I alter the code so it checks for these?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No he said you could get help from forums etc. ;)

Comment: Note you can make your pattern a little shorter and easier to read by using the /i case insensitivity flag. For example, instead of `/[0-9A-Za-z]/` you can use `/[0-9a-z]/i`.

Answer (score 1):

To match something you've already captured, use a backreference. A backreference is `\1`, `\2`, `\3` and so on, where the number is the position of the capturing subpattern you are referencing.

For instance, `/^([0-9A-Za-z])\1/` will match any number or letter, followed by the same number or letter.

Comment: I don't get it implemented in the code, could you maybe make an example?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatenate your strings,

```
return preg_match("/([0-9A-Za-z])\1-([0-9A-Za-z])\2-([0-9A-Za-z])\3/", $kenteken);
```

Comment: Maybe you don't need both " and /?  I tested it using http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/